# How do i render components with angular cli 5, not showing anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bash

[Index html page don't show anything, not event "App works" like a simples initial project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUqB4.png)

ng --version

Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.9.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0
: 0.0.35
: 0.0.22
: 0.0.41
: 1.1.0
: 1.9.0
: 0.1.10
: 0.0.10
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0

Mac OS Sierra

Repro steps

app-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
{path:'', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.component.html
app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
HomeComponent,
AboutComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html

AngularProjeto
After all this i don't get anything when a run "ng serve --open", not even an error

this is the link for pra project

https://github.com/afabricioa/startAngular

someone to help?

tried again just cloning my repository, then i ran "ng completion --bash", "npm install" and "ng serve --open" and the index page is still blank it appears that angular can't render nothing from components, i ran "ng completion --bash" just in case, but even without this command i still get the same thing

Comment: I've cloned your repo. Did `npm i` and `ng serve`, then visited `http://localhost:4200/` and I can clearly see [`Welcome to app!` message](https://imgur.com/01h9S2a). Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you create `HomeComponent` and `AboutComponent` because I can't seem to find them in your repo.

Comment: It is about that, i can't even see "Welcome to app!" and a did exactly like you did npm i and ng serve

Comment: But you posted a different `app-routing-module.ts` then you have on the repo... Can you try cloning your repo to a new location and not applying any changes to it? Can you see the welcome screen then?

Comment: Sorry, the code here it is not supposed to have "about" or "home" components, it was a different code, but the conde in git repo is not showing "Welcome to app!"

Comment: Sorry bout that, i posted a different app-routing-module.ts, a little different from the one on repo, but i just tried here the repo one and still didn't get anything, cloned the repo then "npm i" and "ng serve"

Comment: web pack is compiled successfully but i still get a blank index page with no "Welcome to app!"

Comment: Does `npm i` command complete successfully by saying `added 1149 packages in 18.519s`? Does `ng serve` say `webpack: Compiled successfully.` at the end? Did you visit `localhost:4200`? The port is **IMPORTANT**! Did you open up inspector? Is there anything in the console?

Comment: npm i - added 1149 packages in 17.909s
webpack: Compiled successfully. is ate the end
console don't show any error or anything and i am visiting http://localhost:4200 and is always the same blank page

Comment: We will continue this once you [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it seems to be anything with my angular, because i tried to clone other repos and projects and none of them works here, all repos and codes show the same blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I downloaded your project, it is displaying the app root component HTML. So i'm not sure why you're having this issue. I am not able to reproduce.

Comment: It says [`This project was generated with Angular CLI version 1.6.0.`](https://github.com/afabricioa/startAngular#angularprojeto) and current is [`1.6.1`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli). So it's not that far behind.

Comment: I can reproduce my project, but it seems that angular is not rendering components, i'm trying to start with angular, but i'm creating a simple initial project but it is not showing anything from any component, even when i create a home or about.

Answer (score -1):

Someone deleted my previous post but I can deduct some possible reasons for your problem.
It cannot be because of the hardware because I have had the same problem before even on windows 10 and 7 both on desktop and laptop and Linux 16.04 lots.
I've tested both on chrome and firefox and the same problems are there.
I suggest you have a look at this https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular5-example-app.
It is the angular 5 example app and it is fully functioning. Also, you can try the demo here https://angularexampleapp.com/